# Are valuables used for anything or can I sell them all?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

There is a "Valuables" tab in the inventory, and on first glance it looks like the stuff in that category isn't used for anything. But I'm also not that far into the game and want to avoid selling anything that might still have some use.

Is everything in the valuables category useless and can I simply sell all of it without worrying?

Comment: I know monster research items get lumped into the valuables tab, and those can be turned in near the war room.  It does say when you mouse over them that they are used for research though.  Don't know about more standard items (paragon busts, gems, etc.)

Answer (score 12):

Some of the items in the valuables category are used for researching your enemies; these can be turned into the table next to Minaeve - a quest in Haven should show up early on to tell you about this.

> A similar table will be in the tower in Skyhold after the Inquisition moves there.

Some of the items in this category are also used for requisitions. Since there's nothing to indicate which valuables are or aren't used in them, and the area requisitions seem to be repeatable infinitely (it just picks another random one from the list for that area each time), it's probably not all that safe to sell any valuables, unless you can get a list of all the requisitions. That said, since the area requisitions only really give Power, you could just ignore them, and only hoard valuables if they're used in another one.

Oh, and of course, there's also the ability to mark items in other categories as valuables, which means basically any item can be in the valuables category. This seems to be intended as a way to mark things for later sale, by hitting Sell All on the valuables category once you get to a shop. This works alright, provided you turn in research first, but only if you don't care about the requisition items being lost.

Comment: Actually, the items needed for requisitions also end up in this tab (example: decorative gemstones) and should not be sold.

Comment: @spugsley Huh, thought I'd accidentally sold something for one of those. Kinda odd that those ones don't then end up in Crafting Materials. *grumble*. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The safe bet is to turn in any requisitions and research items first. They all get lumped in valuables. You might have all the required items to complete a requisition, and then sell them accidentally. Your can always buy them back from the same merchant, but if you are not careful you might return to haven and realize you sold those spider ichors and have to farm more.

Answer (score 1):

There are items like the Sad Weapon Schematics that require Sad Splinters, which you get from breaking down doors on keeps, however they are listed as valuables.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly ever used anything from valuables on my first 120 hour play through. Their pretty redundant. I say sell em they aren't worth hoarding. I was hoping the rings amulets could be crafting materials but sadly you cannot create your own accessories. D:

Answer (score 0):

Unique requisition items and research material does not get sold when you hit the sell all button.  And as for actual valuables like gold bracelet silver rings simple pendants lockets can all be sold.  And if for some odd reason you need valuables again there's a merchant in Val Royeaux That will sell them to you.

Answer (score -1):

If you beat the game, you should sell the items. Once you have beaten the game, you do not need power, unless you still have a areas to scout. Regardless, side quests will earn more power.